# Virtual machines can't ping each other

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, vmware

I have 2 VMs set up on VMware (XP and Kali).  The network adapter on my XP box is Custom: VMnet2, and on my Kali box it has NAT and also Custom: VMnet2

I have changed my `/etc/network/interface` on Kali with the following:

```
allow-eth0
iface eth0 inet static 
address 10.0.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.0.1

# the primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

I have set up my Windows XP to use the following ip `10.0.0.2` with gateway `10.0.0.1`

Why can't they ping each other?

Comment: Why the *virtualbox* tag, when you are discussing *VMWare*?

Comment: hi , i have tried on virtual box aswell with no success , it doesnt matter if it is on VMWare or Virtualbox aslong as i can have a working solution

Answer (score 0):

forgive me If I'm wrong, but somewhere in there you need a DNS/DHCP daemon/server.

WinXP --NET--> DHCP/DNS/ROUTER <---NET--- Kali

Unless ur gateway is indeed naturally 10.0.0.1, yu can't just invent one, it must be physical or software ;)

Comment: Hi , thanks for the reply , i am setting up a malware analysis lab (xp) which wouldnt be safe if i had it connected to the internet , seeing that i put both guest os's on the same network (VMnet2) i thought they could atleast ping eachother and only eachother (that is all i need)